# What should I do to know that my dog will be safe if I go on vacation

Tags: dogs, safety

What should I do to know that my dog will be safe if I go on vacation? Sometimes I go on vacation and I leave my dog at home. What should I do so they will be safe and not scared? On New Year's there are fireworks that scare them, old food can't be removed, new water can't be poured, and other things could happen.

Comment: Hire a dogsitter. The nearest pet-shelter should have a list of reliable persons for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't *ever* leave a dog alone, unattended for an extended period of time. What if your dog trips on some wires and a TV drops on him? Or he gets sick or has food poisoning? Or he drank all the water. In addition dogs need exercise, and have to have a chance to take care of their bodily functions. There's just too much risk involved.

You can probably find a reliable pet-sitter or pet hostel in most major cities - we leave our dog at a place that specialises in it, but we have a nice lady in our neighbourhood who babysits a mini schnauzer when his owners are on vacation. The peace of mind is well worth the money.